How do I ask a CommonLisp system to lookup symbols dynamically at runtime in compiled functions?
As a preamble, I am implementing two simple commands I can use via a little package in SBCL, which emulates Allegro repl. The package is sb-aclrepl, found in the contrib folder in SBCL sources. The commands should start and stop Slynk or Swank (was Astrid Lindgren a secret lisper?), depending on which I want to use. I am using both but on different machines, until I make my mind which I prefer.
Here is some intro code:
(in-package :sb-aclrepl)

(defstruct app-server
  (name "SLYNK" :type string)
  (port 4004 :type integer))

(defvar *server* (make-instance 'app-server))

That just stores a string and a number for ports. We need those to lookup symbols later, and to control on which port server starts (I found that Swank sometimes starts on some random port).
I would like to be able to write a simple code like this:
(defun server-run (&optional impl)
  (when impl
    (setf (app-server-name *server*) (string-upcase impl)))
  (ql:quickload (app-server-name *server*))
  (let ((cl:*package* (find-package (app-server-name *server*))))
    (create-server :port (incf (app-server-port *server*)) :dont-close t)))

(defun server-stop ()
  (let ((cl:*package* (find-package (app-server-name *server*))))
    (dolist (connection *connections*)
      (close-connection connection nil nil))))

This obviously does not work since the symbol lookup is done at read time. When the compiler compiles the code, it resolves Slynk or Swank related symbols to the current package. We get sb-aclrepl::*connections* instead of say, swank::*connections*.
We could do something like this:
(defun server-run (&optional impl)
  (when impl
    (setf (app-server-name *server*) (string-upcase impl)))
  #-(or :slynk :swank)
  (if (or (equal (app-server-name *server*) "SLYNK")
          (equal (app-server-name *server*) "SWANK"))
      (ql:quickload (app-server-name *server*))
      (error "I don't know how to load ~a~%" (app-server-name *server*)))
  #+:slynk
  (slynk:create-server :port (incf (app-server-port *server*)) :dont-close t)
  #+:swank
  (swank:create-server :port (incf (app-server-port *server*)) :dont-close t)
  #-(or :slynk :swank) ;; we shouldn't be here
  (error "I don't know how to start ~a~%" (app-server-name *server*)))

(defun server-stop ()
  #+slynk
  (dolist (connection slynk::*connections*)
    (slynk::close-connection connection nil nil))
  #+swank
  (dolist (connection swank::*connections*)
    (swank::close-connection connection nil nil))
  #-(or :slynk :swank) ;; we shouldn't be here
  (error "I don't know how to stop ~a~%" (app-server-name *server*)))

The problem with this is that either one has to be loaded at compile time. In practical terms, when we load ASDF system, either Slynk or Swank should be loaded as a dependency, or we have to tell ASDF somehow to load one of those. A simple solution is to control this via an environment variable, but we are in the land of C and C++ now. We have written two different applications, one per each application server, and if-defing which one is used at compile time as in a C program. Lisp is supposed to be a language for symbolic computations, isn't it? Can we do better? Can we not just say (server-start 'swank) and everything should just work?
To make that happen, we need to dynamically load required server, and to dynamically resolve symbols when an action is requested.
I was able to find two solutions, of which one is completely unacceptable, and the other one
is inefficient. The first one was to force evaluation at execution time via (eval-when (:execute) ...).
That one is not acceptable in this particular case, because it seems to ask for every caller of the function to also be evaluated at the runtime. That is orthogonal to setting up a dispatch table with available commands so I can call this function via an interactive command. If I add :compile-toplevel that forces evaluation at compile time which is what we started with. As an alternative, I could perhaps rewrite sb-aclrepl to work differently, but that is out of scope for this question and out of my interest too.
The second one, the one I present here, is to generate the code via macro, and than arrange for the macro to be somehow evaluated at runtime. It is acceptable to evaluate this at the top level scope, so I just use eval here:
(defun server-run (&optional impl)
  (when impl
    (setf (app-server-name *server*) (string-upcase impl)))
  (unless (find-package (app-server-name *server*))
    (ql:quickload (app-server-name *server*)))
  (eval
   `(let ((run (find-symbol "CREATE-SERVER" (app-server-name *server*))))
      (funcall run :port (incf (app-server-port *server*)) :dont-close t))))

(defun server-stop ()
  (eval
   `(let* ((server (app-server-name *server*))
           (close (find-symbol "CLOSE-CONNECTION" server))
           (connections (symbol-value (find-symbol "*CONNECTIONS*" server))))
      (dolist (connection connections)
        (funcall close connection nil nil)))))

As a note, the actual interface is (server-run STRING), not (server-run SYMBOL). This is due to how sb-aclrepl works. I can type: :sr swank at the repl, and it will translate symbol to a string for me, so we don't call symbol-name in server-run.
However, that is obviously computationally less efficient, since eval forces the code compilation at the runtime. This is obviously not a performance intensive code. It is used interactively and once at the start and at the end of a session, so I can live with eval.
However, for my own curiosity and learning purpose, I have a question: how can I ask a CommonLisp system to lookup symbols at runtime without using eval and a macro, or without forcing the entire call-chain to be evaled at runtime. Is it possible, and if it is, how do I do it, preferably in a portable way?
Edit: I think progv special form could also be used instead of eval, but I just came up on the thought, will try a bit later in the evening.

(eval '(expression)) is the same as just (expression) unless it contains symbols that would be references to local variables from outside the eval. Your expressions don't have anything like that, there's no need for eval. FUNCALL will look up the function dynamically evan without EVAL.

(defvar *server* (make-instance 'app-server)) are your complications coming from this not being in a function?

@Barmar Yes indeed. I am not sure where my thoughts were. I had a different code from the beginning, but reworked badly from the question.

@Ehvince I don't think so. I could put it in a function, or initiate in some function, or even refactor out of the struct, but I don't think it really matters.

Whats with Astrid Lindgren? I didn't got the joke :D

@Gwang-Jin Kim Just a (distant) reference to Pippi Långstrump (Pippi Longstocking), and two characters from the book Kling and Klang (two police officers). Slynk and Swank sounds like names Astrid would give to her characters.

@myname thanks for the explanation! :D I knew Pipi Langstrumpf (in German :D), but didn't know the name of the officers.

Improve the code
Why this
(eval
 `(let ((run (find-symbol "CREATE-SERVER" (app-server-name *server*))))
    (funcall run :port (incf (app-server-port *server*)) :dont-close t)))

and not just this
(let ((run (find-symbol "CREATE-SERVER" (app-server-name *server*))))
  (funcall run :port (incf (app-server-port *server*)) :dont-close t))

?
Similar, why not just this:
(defun server-stop ()
  (let* ((server (app-server-name *server*))
         (close (find-symbol "CLOSE-CONNECTION" server))
         (connections (symbol-value (find-symbol "*CONNECTIONS*" server))))
    (dolist (connection connections)
      (funcall close connection nil nil))))

Runtime Lookup
Common Lisp is designed so that there is no symbol lookup at runtime for function calls. It also allows the compiler to check function calls against a defined function specification: correct number of args, correct keyword arguments, and more.
Finding a symbol from a package is done with FIND-SYMBOL. FIND-SYMBOL does not create new symbols. It has two arguments: the name of the symbol and the package of the symbol.
CL-USER 58 > (defpackage "FOO" (:use))
#<The FOO package, 0/16 internal, 0/16 external>

CL-USER 59 > (intern "HELLO" "FOO")
FOO::HELLO
NIL

CL-USER 60 > (find-symbol "HELLO")  ; -> wrong package
NIL
NIL

CL-USER 61 > (find-symbol "HELLO" "FOO")
FOO::HELLO
:INTERNAL

Above is all sequentially executed.
READ and READ-FROM-STRING also do symbol lookup (remember to set *read-eval* to nil to prevent read time evaluation:
CL-USER 62 > (let ((*read-eval* nil))
               (read-from-string "(FOO::HELLO 1 2 3)"))
(FOO::HELLO 1 2 3)
18

CL-USER 63 > (describe (first *))

FOO::HELLO is a SYMBOL
NAME          "HELLO"
VALUE         #<unbound value>
FUNCTION      #<unbound function>
PLIST         NIL
PACKAGE       #<The FOO package, 1/16 internal, 0/16 external>

Now we want to call some function if we, at runtime, know its name and package:
CL-USER 64 > (defun callnew (package name &rest args)
               (apply (find-symbol name package)
                      args))
CALLNEW

CL-USER 65 > (defun foo::hello (a b c) (* a b c))
FOO::HELLO

CL-USER 66 > (callnew "FOO" "HELLO" 1 2 3)
6

The obvious drawbacks:

if the function or package is not existing, one gets a runtime error -> think: how to handle this error?

if the function or package is not existing, one does not get a compile time error

if the function or package is not existing, the compiler can't check arguments against the specified parameter list

we need to make sure that the case is right, symbols in Common Lisp have by default internally upper case names


Security
Think about the consequences of loading and executing code or data at runtime. One could also add checks to callnew, such that only certain symbols can be called.

A brain dump!
The original code was somewhat different:
;; (let ((app-server-port 4004)
;;       start stop)
( ... )
;;   (defun server-stop (&optional (port app-server-port))
;;     (eval `(,stop ,port))))
I reworked it for the question, but eval + macro were left. Indeed, that does the runtime lookup without need for eval. However, a following question: do I have to "manually" lookup each symbol? Is there any way I can let-bind package and make SBCL understand what I am doing, so it lookup symbols at the runtime, without manually fiddling with find-symbol and find-package?

Thanks for pointing it out by the way!

@myname Are you looking for uiop:symbol-call :package :name ?

@Ehvince I don't know; I wasn't aware of that one, will check it up.
As said in the intro, I would like to be able to let-bind package, and to have symbols looked up in the bound package at the runtime in the lexical scope of that let-binding. While, yes, I had a brain freeze in the example with eval + macro here; the real question is how do I do this without this manual lookups. I'll check the uiop suggestion, thanks, and I will see if I can make some macro with progv, still didn' have time to code something.

@Rainer Have I missed your "Runtime lookup" part at first reading completely? Thank you very much for this thorough answer. The most important part is that CL is not designed for runtime lookup. That explains quite a bit. I'll have to read through it a bit more and test and reflect more over it. By the way, later today, when I thought more of it, this reminds me a lot of loading functions from .so/.dll objects in C. I guess find-symbol/find-package are in some sense, similar to finding a function in a shared library, and setting a function pointer somewhere in user code. Sort of?

I am not addressing the direct question about evaluating code at runtime, I'm trying to show an approach that seems to me to be a bit more straightforward and reliable, by defining proper systems for each backend. This is different from what you had with reader conditionals: instead, each backend is defined in a distinct file, as a method of a generic function. More precisely:
In api.lisp
(defgeneric api:server-start (type &key port))
(defgeneric api:server-stop (server))

(defvar *server* nil)

(defmethod api:server-start :around (_ &key &allow-other-keys)
  (let ((server *server*))
    (when server
      (with-simple-restart (continue "Stop existing server")
        (error "A server is already running"))
      (api:server-stop server)
      (setf *server* nil))
    (setf *server* (call-next-method)))

;; etc

In swank.lisp
(defmethod api:server-start ((type (eql :swank)) &key port)
  (swank:create-server :port port))

So far, there is no suprise, you define a contract for starting and stopping servers, as well as a way to have a single active server at a time.
The rest of the problem is solved in the domain of systems.
You define an app/base system, a app/swank and app/slynk systems, which depend on the app/base and respectively the swank.lisp and slynk.lisp files.
You can quickload either app/swank or app/slynk, or both (or an entierly other one), and in all cases you register enough methods to have a proper working server for each backend.
Eventually, you can have a top system app with a utility that wraps things up nicely for the user by having a function that quickloads the appropriate systems:
(defvar *known-backends*
  '((:slink . :app/slynk)
    (:swank . :app/swank)))

(defun start () (error "no active backend, call LOAD-BACKEND first"))
(defun stop () (error "no active backend, call LOAD-BACKEND first"))

(defun load-backend (name)
  (let ((entry (assoc name *known-backends*)))
    (unless entry (error "not a known backend: ~s" name))
    ;; after this call, the methods are registered hopefully
    (ql:quickload (cdr entry))
    (flet ((start () (api:server-start name :port port))
           (stop () (api:server-stop api:*server*)))
      (setf (symbol-function 'start) #'start)
      (setf (symbol-function 'stop) #'stop))))

Or something else entirely. What doesn't work reliably I think is defining a :before method for server-start that quickloads the necessary system; given that compute-applicable-methods is already called at this point, I think it's undefined for CLOS if the set of methods changes while dispatching. But anyway, the important point is that any kind of runtime decision about which backend to use is reduced to a small set of functions.

Thanks! I had some thoughts about using CLOS, and different files, but for the question, I coded everything in one file, I thought the principle would be the same, if it was in two different files. But I haven't thought of two different (sub)systems.  Sounds like a simple and useful idiom for frameworks where implementation does not have necessary all the parts? I'll have to try it bit later. Thank you very much! Someone should write a book about common Lisp idioms like this or perhaps persuade Edi W. to update his Recipes book.
